# Perform action when click anywhere else

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a div with a class
Then how to perform an action by clicking anywhere else except the specified class
Using jquery

Answer (score 4):

You would probably want to use the `not` selector: https://api.jquery.com/not-selector. For example:

```js
$(':not(.class)').click(function(){
  //logic
});
```